# Sails-Mongo native query to a specific collection

Tags: mongodb, collections, sails.js, native, populate

Im using Sails v1.0 with **sails-mongo** as an adapter and im having a memory leak in a simple populate between two models that have a many-to-many association.

I got into the mongo shell and saw that sails created a collection for this association, something like "model1_models2_model2_models1" filled with objects like "{id, idModel1, idModel2}" to represent the association.

The thing is that I want to avoid the "populate" that is making the leak but **I don't know hot to get to this collection using a native query** and I did not find any answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Get access to the native MongoDB client via the default Sails datastore.
var db = sails.getDatastore("nameOfTheDatastore").manager;
db.collection('user').find().toArray(console.log);
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51382322/2) to the question [Sails-Mongo native query to a specific collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382322/sails-mongo-native-query-to-a-specific-collection) by the OP [alan bendjuya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9524333/alan-bendjuya) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>